# Why does an instance variable, which is a list, grow in a for loop?

Tags: python-2.7, instance-variables

In the code below, I am expecting that a new instance of MyClass with the name 'obj' will be created every time inside the for loop. Therefore, the output should be [1] every time. But obj.mylist seems to grow. What am I missing?

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__( self, mylist_=[] ):
        self.mylist = mylist_ 

    def addData( self ):
        self.mylist.append( 1 )

for i in range(5):
    obj = MyClass()
    obj.addData()
    print obj.mylist
```

The output is:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: There's a good logic explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: @Andrew L -- No, the problem here is using a mutable default argument, not the problem in that question.

Comment: @bgporter Yeah, my bad. Retracted CV

Comment: The post listed above by @skovorodkin is a good dupe for this question.

Comment: I found the following link in @skovorodkin 's comment which answers my question: [effbot.org/zone/default-values](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, default values for arguments are created **once** at the time that the statement that **defines the function** is executed.

Please refer to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values):

> The default values are evaluated at the point of function definition in the defining scope, so that…
>
> <…>
>
> **Important warning:** The default value is evaluated only once. This makes a difference when the default is a mutable object such as a list, dictionary, or instances of most classes.
>
> <…>
>
> — [4.7.1. Default Argument Values — Python 3.5.2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values).

This reference also contains the example of not following the warning — a very similar case and observed behavior.

Additional references:

- [Using a mutable default value as an argument: Anti-pattern](http://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html#anti-pattern).
- Not a bug: [Issue 448911: Empty list as default argument problem - Python tracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue448911).
- [Common Gotchas: Mutable Default Arguments — The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments).
- [Python insight: beware of mutable default values for arguments - Eli Bendersky's website](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/01/16/python-insight-beware-of-mutable-default-values-for-arguments).
- [Gotcha — Mutable default arguments | Python Conquers The Universe](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/mutable-default-arguments/).